# Animate HTML Menu bar item

Tags: html, css, animation, menubar

I am trying to create an animated menu bar, in which the background block moves from the current selection to the latest one. For an example, have a look at http://www.creative-jar.com/. I would like to accomplish this in the simplest possible manner (perhaps using only HTML and CSS). Any help will be really appreciated.

As I am new to web development, thoughts on whether this sort of animation is a good or bad idea are also welcome.

Comment: I don't think this is really an answerable uestion, but it's certainly possible using only HTML and CSS if you're willing to drop support for IE. [Mozdev has some good reading on the subject.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_animations)

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you describe: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/